# Receive inputs from CLI and update yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, argparse, pyyaml

The program should read/write the existing YAML file and provide a command-line interface to add new contacts and to show details of existing contacts.

The below code runs but is not taking any inputs rather it just displays the data given

```
Namespace(List=None, age=23, email='viv.co.in@gmail.com', name='vivek', number=17675244953)

import argparse
import yaml
from pprint import pprint

class CLI(object):

    def book(self):
        self.create_parser()
        self.options = self.parse_args()
        pprint(self.options)

    def create_parser(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Phonebook:')
        g = self.parser.add_argument_group('Device Targets')
        g.add_argument('--List', type=argparse.FileType(mode='r'))
        g.add_argument('--name', default=[], action='append')
        g.add_argument('--age', default=[],  action='append', type=int,)
        g.add_argument('--number', default=[], action='append', type=int)
        g.add_argument('--email', default=[], action='append')

    def parse_args(self):
        args = self.parser.parse_args()
        config_file =  "{name: vivek, age: 23, email: viv.co.in@gmail.com, number: 17675244953}"
        data = yaml.load(config_file)
        for key, value in data.items():
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    for v in value:
                        getattr(args, key, []).append(v)
                else:
                    setattr(args, key, value)
        return args

cli = CLI()
cli.book()
```

The expected output should be of below format:

```
py-contacts --show TestName # shows details of saved contact of person with "TestName" ... 

py-contacts --add NewName --number 012345 --email test@mail.com # adds new contact to YAML .. py-contacts --list # shows a list of all saved contacts
```

Comment: Looks like it has just inserted the `yaml` values in the `args` Namespace.  I don't see anything in your parser definition that would accept the `--show` or `--add` flags.  For debugging I'd suggest adding a `print(args)` before handling the `yaml`, so you have a clear idea of what the parser is doing.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly: you want to print out how to invoke the py-contacts tool with the contents of the yaml file?

Comment: None of your `data` values are lists, so the only action is the `setattr`.  There's no appending.  `print(data)` to verify that.

Comment: Note also that all `args` attributes, except `List`, are lists, default an empty one. I wonder if you have that list instance test backwards, instead of checking `data`, you should be checking `args`?  In other words, do you want `args` to modify defaults from `yaml` or the other way around.  Also the most common `argparse` definitions don't use `append` action; they simply store a string or int in the attribute, or leave it the default (default default is `None`).  `append` isn't needed unless you need to repeat the flag.

Comment: PyYAML's load is documented to be potentially unsafe, you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @Anthon, in this example the source is in the script itself.  I imagine in production it's supposed to be a default configuration file provided as part of the project itself, not a file imported from an unknown source.

Comment: yes the code is imperfect... but need help to rectify it